# How to insert and return the full object in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655142/insert-with-hibernate-with-child-objects-does-not-return-full-object), but my problem is specifically with Spring Boot's native CrudRepository and JpaRepository, which do not appear to have a refresh() method.  I am saving a new object that contains IDs for existing child objects.  The application is RESTful, and the data being inserted is JSON from the client.  The new record is inserted correctly, but the child objects in the return value still contain only IDs.  Is there a Spring Boot equivalent of refresh()?  Do I need to create a custom repository with access to an EntityManager?

I should add that using findOne() after the insert does not solve the problem.  The child objects are still incomplete.  However, when I select the inserted record in a separate REST call, the object is complete along with all of the child objects.

The code is below.  As you can see the repository and service method are so simple that I didn't see what to do.  Refreshing looked like something Spring Boot should handle automatically.

Note:  The SO comment form is removing the parameters from CrudRepository and some
return types.

### Volume.java

```
    @Entity
    @JsonSerialize(using = VolumeSerializer.class)
    public class Volume implements Protectable {

        public static final int ATTACHED_STATE = 1;
        public static final int DETACHED_STATE = 0;
        public static final int SUSPENDED_STATE = -1;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        private String name;
        @OneToOne
        private VolumeType type;
        private int size;
        @OneToOne
        private UserGroup userGroup;
        @OneToOne
        private Region region;
        @OneToOne
        private State state;
        @OneToOne
        private Status status;
        @OneToOne
        private Alarm alarmStatus;
        private long createdDate;
        @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint default 0")
        private long lastModifiedDate = 0;
        @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint default 0")
        private boolean monitoringEnabled = false;
        @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint default 0")
        private boolean encrypted = false;
        @OneToOne
        private Snapshot snapshot;
        @ManyToOne
        private Instance instance;
    /*
    after this there are constructors, a long list of getters for the properties above
    a static Builder class and @PrePersist and @PreUpdate methods
    */
    ...
```

### VolumeRepository.java

```java
    /**
     * For accessing Volume information
     */
    public interface VolumeRepository extends CrudRepository {
       List findByUserGroupId(long groupId);
    }
```

### VolumeService.java

```
    @Transactional
    public Iterable save(List volumes) {
       return this.repository.save(volumes);
    }
```

### VolumeRouter.java

It's a @RestController.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/volumes", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Iterable create(@RequestBody List volumes) {
        return this.service.save(volumes);
    }
```

### application.properties

(The ddl-auto setting is for development)

```
    # Datasource configuration
    spring.datasource.url=****
    spring.datasource.username=****
    spring.datasource.password=****
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=34000
    spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=55000
    spring.datasource.min-idle=0


    # Hibernate settings
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

### VolumeServiceIT.java

The JSON string shows you what the client expects
to be able to send to the services.  The UserGroup object contains only the 
ID that was sent from the client, but instead it should be the full UserGroup
object.  The same is true for the other child objects.

```
    @Test
    public void createVolume() throws Exception {
        String json = "[{" +
                    "\"name\": \"Test Volume\", " +
                    "\"size\": 24, " +
                    "\"monitoringEnabled\": true, " +
                    "\"encrypted\": true, " +
                    "\"state\": { \"id\": 1 }, " +
                    "\"userGroup\": { \"id\": 1 }, " +
                    "\"region\": { \"id\": 1 }, " +
                    "\"type\": { \"id\": 1 }" +
                "}]";

        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/volumes")
                .principal(token)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(4)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("Test Volume")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].size", is(24)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].userGroup.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].userGroup.name", is("myGroup")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].userGroup.users", isEmptyOrNullString()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].type.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].type.value", is("SSD")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].region.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].region.value", is("us-west")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].state.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].state.value", is("on")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].status", isEmptyOrNullString()))
                        //.andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdDate", is(1425240151000L)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].monitoringEnabled", is(true)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].encrypted", is(true)));
    }
```

Comment: how are you performing the persistence? could you post the code being used?

Comment: Fransisco, thanks for responding.  I added the relevant code.  As you can see, it is very simple--just invoking save() on a CrudRepository or JpaRepository.  The problem occurs either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting with a colleague, I injected the EntityManager into the VolumeService above and called refresh on the Volume.

```
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

    ...

        @Transactional
        public Iterable save(List volumes) {
            Iterable result = this.repository.save(volumes);

            for (Volume volume : result){
                entityManager.refresh(volume);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Note that, while I preferred this option,my colleague recommended fetching the child objects, adding them to the new Volume, then saving the Volume, which would obviously work.  I didn't want to have to do that, however.